# Number of subsets with subscripts being a multiple of each other?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, contest-math

Let set $S = \{a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_{12}\}$, where all 12 elements are distinct. We wish to form subsets, each of which contains one or more of the elements of set $S$ (including the possibility of using all the elements of $S$). The only restriction is that the subscript of each element in a specific set must be an integer multiple of the smallest subscript in that set. For example, $\{a_2, a_4, a_6\}$ is an acceptable set, as is $\{a_6\}.$ How many such sets can be formed?

My approach to this problem was to start off with using a1 as the lowest subscript, leading to 2^11 options for the rest of the subsets that use a1. I then repeated the process up to a6, and added 1 for the rest of the subsets a7 through a10. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This approach seems right.  If you share the details, we might be able to figure out if you made an error.  Also, there is no need for the element-subscript business, just use $S=\{1,2,3,\ldots, 12\}$.

Comment: Why do you think you are doing something wrong?

Comment: @vadim123 So here's the rest of my approach: If 2 is the smallest number of the subset, then there are 2^5 different subsets that can me made. If 3 is the lower subset, then there are 8 subsets that can be made. If 4 is the lowest subset, the there are 4 subsets that can be made. If 5 is the lowest subset, there are two subsets that can be made. If 6 is the lowest subset, there are also 2 subsets that can be made. Finally for subsets 7-12, there is only 1 subset each that can be made. This should be 2048+32+8+4+2+2+1*6 which equals 2102, which is the correct answer. LOL i just added wrong.

Comment: @vadim123 thanks for making me look back over my work, I discovered that I added an extra 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your value of $2^{11}$ for sets including $a_1$ is correct.  Then for sets not including $a_1$ but including $a_2$ you have $2^5$ choices as there are $5$ numbers divisible by $2$ not including $2$.  For sets with smallest element $a_3$ you have $2^3$ choices, for sets with smallest element $a_4$ you have $2^2$ choices, for sets with smallest element $a_5,a_6$ you have two choices, and for smallest element $a_7$ through $a_{12}$ you have one.  The total is then 
$$2^{11}+2^5+2^3+2^2+2\cdot 2 +6=2102$$